# Solution to $\frac{1}{6}g''=v g^3+k g^3-k g$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a nice problem with a not-so simple solution. Consider the following differential equation:
$$\frac{1}{6}g''=v g^3+kg^3 - k g$$
with boundary conditions $g(0)=0$ and $g(\infty)=1$, where $k>0$ and $v \geq 0$.

What i've tried so far:
Multiply by $g'$ and integrate once:
$$(g')^2=3\left[(k+v)g^4-2k g^2+(k-v)\right]$$
where I've added the integration constant $(v+k)$ to ensure that $g(\infty)=1$ and thus $g'(\infty)=0$.

which has a nice solution for $v=0$, $g'=3k(1-g^2)$, thus $g=\tanh{(3k x)}$. However,such a nice factorization of the polynomial does not hold for $v \neq 0$.

This is where your help may come in, if anyone has any suggestions, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can make this simpler with regards to constants. You can rewrite the problem, without loss of generality, in the form
$$g'' = \alpha g^3 - \beta g, \quad \alpha, \beta >0$$

Comment: Are you playing with black holes? It looks like the general solution remains trapped within bounds for some values of $g'(0)$ but escapes for others.

Comment: No actually this is regarding non-adsorbing charged polymers near neutral walls. The non-adsorbing boundary condition imposes $g(0)=0$ and far away from the surface (in the bulk of the polymer solution) the solution is homogeneous, thus $g'(\infty)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends, of course, on the boundary conditions. As written the problem actually has no solution because $g\to1$ as $x\to\infty$ is obtainable only when $v=0$. For nonzero $v$ you find that assuming $g\to1$ gives the second derivative a nonzero limit which is contradictory. If you mean to force a constant value at infinity, you must allow this constant to vary with $v$ and $k$ so that it properly corresponds to a zero of $g''$. Then, it turns out,  you always have the hyperbolic tangent solution.

To wit, render $g=ah$ for some constant $a$, and then

$\dfrac16ah''=(v+k)a^3h^3-kah$

Then you eliminate the constant term from the first integral equation by setting $a$ to match $(v+k)a^3$ with $ka$. So for a nonzero solution as you presumably want,

$a=\pm\sqrt{\dfrac{k}{v+k}}$

where the sign corresponds to an overall factor of $\pm 1$ in the solution for $g$ itself (the differential equation has odd parity). For this value of $a$ the constant-limit boundary condition turns out to be $h=1,\therefore g=a\overset{generally}{\not=}1$.

When the substitution is carried through, the equation for $h$ becomes identical to the equation for $g$ already solved with $v=0$, so

$h=\tanh(3kx),g=a\tanh(3kx).$

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Don't you end up with the same problem though? As in this case the integration constant obtained after multiplying with h' and integrating is equal to $\frac{k}{4}\frac{1-2a}{a^4}$, yielding an polynomial that is not factor-able as squares. As a note, this integration constant is obtained because $g(\infty)=1$ thus $h(\infty)=\frac{1}{a}$.

Comment: What I find is that the only positive constants $g$ and $h$ can approach as $x\to\infty$ are respectively $a$ and $1$. The limit has to be a zero of the expression for $g''$ or $h''$. See my edit.